# Do we need primary key on table referencing two other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, primary-key

I have a table having columns `ProductTypeID, BrandID, SupportedBatteryID`, which stores `batteryID`s  supported by a particular product.

Non of the columns here are unique, So do i need a primary key on these kind of tables?

If i will add a primary key will it increase the performance while searching batteries for a particular product by using product id?

Comment: You cannot have keys unless there is a candidate key. That being said, good table design *dictates* that every record has a key. In this case I suspect that the entire record is a multi-column candidate key - and can thus be used as a PK. (But you'll need to look at - or discuss - the data in more detail.) Anyway, keys don't improve performance - *indexes* do. But the PK is normally also a clustered index. In this case, there might be a *non-key* index added over ProductTypeID to help with queries, if it's not already included in a clustered PK as the first column.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy Is it a one-many or one-one relationship , I mean for a productId is there only a single `BatteryID` supported or multiple batteries can be supported for a particular ID ?

Comment: @SurajSingh: For a single product multiple battries are supported, thats why product id can not be primary key

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy You can use compound key on three columns that will help in removing duplicate values and may increase performance in searching, try using  Sql Profiler for comparing performances .

Answer (score 1):

You can build a clustered index on (`ProductId, SupportedBatteryId`).
This will help you without creating a Primary key